# Using select box option text set it selected

Tags: php, jquery, json

I found city name in my json array but using of that value city name I want to set particular option selected in selcetbox using jQuery.

```
<select id="city_id">
 <option value="28">Lee</option>
 <option value="32">MAIDENHEAD</option>
</select>
```

And every time city name is changed in json array.

Here my efforts

```
function city(data) {
      var result = JSON.parse(data);

      $.each(result,function(key,value){
        console.log(result[key]);

        if(key == "line_1")
        {
            $("#address").val(result[key]);
        }
        if(key == "town")
        {
            $("#city_id").val(result[key]);
            $('#city_id option').text(value);
        }
      });
    }
```

Comment: Can you share your json array or jsfiddle

Comment: what have you tried ? why tag PHP ? Also, always give `<select>` a `name` attribute

Comment: Where is your effort?

Comment: @rmondesilva : i added my efforts

Comment: @Raptor : only it has id

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Your question is unclear for me where u use city function ? what come to parameter? what is key == line_1 and key == town ?

Comment: Is the data coming from database using server side languages?

Comment: yes, data is coming from database using server side language, but data is in json_encode formate